# How to redirect in try/catch when stripe payment error in laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, response

I have a problem with handling Stripe payment errors.
If the payment succeed, everything works fine, but if the payment failed, I have the classic laravel error page, with the right payment problem, like "Your card has insufficient funds.". But I cannot redirect the user to another page, it just throw me the error. Can someone help me with that?

Here is the code I took from Stripe :

```
try {
    Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

    Stripe\Charge::create ($paymentInfos);
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();

    return redirect('/home')->with('error', $error);
}
```

This code dosen't redirect me to the home page in case of payment failure, it just throw me the laravel error page with the error message.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945857/catch-exception-and-redirect

Comment: The exception likely does not match the type. Try catching generic `\Exception`

Comment: Can you show the error page's content? You need to catch the specific exception that's being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

try {
    Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

```
Stripe\Charge::create ($paymentInfos);
```

} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();

//you can pass the error message throug session 
//use session above in the controller

Session::flash('message', $error);

```
return redirect('/home');
```

}

//after that ypu can display that in your blade from using  the bellow code

@if(Session::has('message'))

{{ Session::get('message') }}

@endif